# Cassandra nodetool shows negative load

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

We are using Cassandra 3.11.4 cluster of 3 nodes in production. We have around 325 GB of data replicated on these nodes. One of cassandra nodetool status is showing negative value. Our production traffic is working fine, Any help on this is appreciated.

```
nodetool status
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  IP1  325.28 GiB  256          100.0%            89388cd276b0  rack3
UN  IP2  -61385108034 bytes  256          100.0%            1942a31c3865  rack1
UN  IP3  313.81 GiB  256          100.0%            8bdf-bae2447e92ec  rack2
```

**Sequence of events:**

We were facing performance issue recently, so we changed readahead value of OS to 8KB and restarted that node. I am not sure if this has affected the nodetool value on that particular node. Now, I have changed the RA values on other nodes as well, waiting if that affects other 2 nodes as well.